# Vue.js is not setting attributes declared in data object array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to vue.js and I want to create some product cards that will dynamically set its attributes through vue.js:

I have this is my HTML snippet:

```
<div id="app">
<card v-for= "products in product" :productname="product.productname"></card>
</div>
```

This is my vue.js template/componet code:

```
Vue.component('card', {
    props: [`productname`, `oldPrice`, `productPrice`, `productdetails`, `imgsrc`],

    template: `
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img-top">
       <img :src="imgsrc">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h2>{{productname}}</h2>
        <p>{{productdetails}}.</p>
        <h6 class="product-price"><span class="old-price">{{oldPrice}} </span>{{productPrice}}</h6>
        <div class="rating">
            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star-half"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>
        </div>
    </div>  
    </div>`
})
```

And this is my vue instance:

```
new Vue({
el: " #app",

data: {
    product: [{
            imgsrc: 'img/41IP6IopkBL.jpg',
            productname: "Pinar Wine top",
            productdetails: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ',
            productPrice: '$200',
            oldPrice: '$400'
        }, {
            imgsrc: 'img/41IP6IopkBL.jpg',
            productname: 'Pinar Wine top',
            productdetails: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur',
            productprice: '$200',
            oldprice: '$400'

        }]
```

But it's just displaying the cards, the attributes (e.g. product name, price etc.) are not displaying. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naming is really important in development to not get confused by what you've been writing. Take a look at your code.

Especially here

```
<card v-for= "products in product" :productname="product.productname"></card>
                                                       ^-- wrong naming here
```

You are accessing `product.productname` but you want to access `products.productname`. As I said, naming is important. You might change the naming for product and products.